# Is it possible to load object (image or something) directly on scene via script in Spark AR?

Tags: javascript, facebook, spark-ar-studio

I want to load image/object from Assets directly on scene in Spark AR by tapping on screen. I know how to track tapping, but didn't find any methods/patches to load something on scene. For example, I can insert a plane on scene before my effect is going to start, but can't do this from code. What should i do to insert a plane via script? Is it possible?

Thanks for answering!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Kindly share what you have tried till now.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately this is not possible. A work-around is to put all the object in the scene that you will need, then hide/show them as needed via script.